# JS not working when turning HTML into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote my web app prototype in static HTML http://footytracker.com/prototype/app/

It uses a js drop down menu for mobile, which works in the prototype.

I've started to port it to the real app which will be done in PHP and the menu dropdown will not work.
http://footytracker.com/app/

I have a feeling it's due to the PHP includes?

UPDATE: Have reordered the JS files to fix the smoothscroll error and this creates a new error:
Uncaught Error: The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist.

I can't understand why the PHP version of the site refuses to load the responsive-nav menu.

I'm pretty new to PHP, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that to be honest. Check you console: `ReferenceError: smoothScroll is not defined fixed-responsive-nav.js:31:4`, line 31 of `fixed-responsive-nav`, `smoothScroll.init();` isn't working.

Comment: Try to move `<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>` above `<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>`.

Comment: as above, seems responsice-nav.js depends on scroll.js, therefor the latter should appear 1st in source code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend you have a read through the [help], and look at some existing questions with a high score, to get an idea of the kind of question we're looking for on the site. In particular, you should include a [minimal example which reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, so that the question remains a valid reference even after you've fixed the code behind those links.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Uncaught Error: The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist

Comment: Check your folder structure. Check your logic in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing you source, I noticed these `js` files are in the wrong order:

```
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
```

Since `fixed-responsive-nav.js` requires a class/function from `scroll.js`, the order needs to be reversed:

```
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
```

If you're not already using them, try checking your browser's Development Tools (press `f12` in Firefox or Chrome) to see any errors in your console or requests.

**EDIT**

Check your order (once again). In your HTML Version, your `.js` files are like so:

```
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script> <!-- Duplicate Include -->
```

But in your PHP Version, they are in a different order:

```
<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script> <!-- Should be above all of them. -->
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
```

Try to fix that and it should work fine for you. This is a layout issue and not a PHP Issue.

**Second Edit**

In your HTML Version, you only have one `.js` file called before creating the `<header>`, `responsive-nav.js`. The rest of your `.js` files are called at the bottom of your page, **after** the `<header>` has been created. Try doing the same on your PHP Version.

Comment: Hi, I should have stated in the original question I had already noticed this error in the DevTools and fixed that problem, the problem isn't actually anything to do with smooth scroll because I removed the scrolling aspect of this menu.

Also the JS is in the wrong order in the prototype and the mobile version of the menu works in that.

I have now updated the JS order and it gives a new error:

Uncaught Error: The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist

Comment: Uh yeah, you probably should have. If it's not this, what other issue are you having? Edit your question to include **all** issues you're having.

Comment: @Neil See my edit, your `.js` files are still in the wrong order. Right click and press `View Source` and compare the two pages; you'll see the issue.

Comment: Sorry I goofed but I have fixed that now and the problem is still existing. The real error is this: Uncaught Error: The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist

Comment: @Neil See my second edit. Move your `.js` files to the right spot. Literally move them to the same place as in your HTML Version.

Comment: Well that's fixed it but I could swear it didn't work like that before, I mean that's where I have them called in the prototype and when I ported it, it didn't work so I started changing it.

Regardless thank you very much Tim!

Comment: @Neil No problem. Something to keep in mind; PHP files are just HTML files with extra `<?php ?>` tags added in. When it comes to layouts, just copy-pasta your HTML and it *should* work just fine.